# Is this a type of swiss chard?

Tags: identification, raised-beds

[image]

I found this plant growing in my raised bed, where watermelon and pumpkin were growing last year. It resembles Swiss Chard (has a red vein) but does not have a red stem.

Answer (score 3):

It looks more like [broad-leaved dock (*Rumex obtusifolius*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumex_obtusifolius), which also develops red veining on older leaves. Another hint that it's dock is that the leaves in your photo have slightly wrinkled edges, but are flat in the center of the leaf; chard's leaves are dimpled throughout the width of the leaf. Chard also has longer stems relative to the overall length of the leaf, and its leaves are held in a more upright position.

It's a perennial weed, and can be considered invasive, so you may be required by local law to eradicate it. I've only ever had young plants in my yard, and I've been able to control it by removing the above-ground part of the plant and digging up about 1' of the taproot.

Comment: Thanks so much, Niall -that's exactly what it is.  Out it goes!  Appreciate all the info - this site is great.  Enjoy your day!  =)